# send data from standby application to active application

Tags: c#-4.0

while my application in standby mode (not the active one),I want it to write in the text box of the active application (while the cursor is in that text box )
that should be done when user press a specific key (for example : ctrl + R)

Comment: What code do you have so far?  What part are you having trouble on?

Comment: I do not know how to make my application in standby mode and make it respond to the key pressed from key board

Comment: and how to pass data to the active application

Comment: You would probably be better off having the active application ask for data from the standby application using some type of interprocess communication. Having the standby application modify data in the active application is more difficult.

Comment: @JimMischel unfortunately  i don't have access to the other program

Comment: I think ayman means "background" instead of "standby".  If an application is actively manipulating the state of another application, it's not standing by.

Comment: @Amy the state which i mean is when my application is running but it minimize to taskbar or next to the clock in the taskbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to have a look to [this sample on code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook) to learn how to cache the key pressed while your application in background to chaek if the ctrl + R keys are pressed then you can use simply use `SendKeys.Send("your text");` method to write in other application text box